# Examples of applications of the Theorems of Pappus and Ménélaüs.

Tags: geometry, reference-request, affine-geometry

I'm going to present an exposition about applications of the Theorems of Pappus and Ménélaüs. I need some simple examples of these two theorems.

Any links, please?

Comment: The most striking thing about Pappus' theorem for me is that for a division ring $D$, $D$ is commutative (a field) iff Pappus holds in the plane $D^2$. That doesn't seem to satisfy your simplicity requirement though

Comment: i need some simple applications of this two theorem that's my requirement.